# Web based 360 spherical video player for self hosted site?

Tags: video, media-player

I have 360 videos which I take with my 360 camera and would like to host and serve these videos. I am looking for an interactive html5 player which I can use in my web page for my visitors to view these videos.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tony,
Are you looking to target a specific platform for your web server?
Also, will the video be streamed live from the device with your application or are you looking to serve up static files? I would imagine the files would be static for different visitors to view different parts of the video at the same time.

Comment: Also, it might help if you could indicate what device you're actually using? I'm not sure if it will make any difference, but some 360 camera only have a wide lens versus other that actually take images at all angles and stitch them together. If you have the latter, I'm not sure how the application would control the data to send. A web API to the device perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site has the tools I wanted. Free and open source. https://pannellum.org/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out the [LEADTOOLS Media Server SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/media-streaming-server) for this. This SDK provides support for streaming to any device, and provides a demo to illustrate the universal player for testing on any device.

This media server can be used to stream either static files or live content. Setting it up as a file server only take a couple of lines. Setting up a live source takes just a couple more as shown here:

```
Leadtools.MediaStreaming.Server mediaServer = new Leadtools.MediaStreaming.Server();
mediaServer.ImportConfigFile("ltmsConfigFolder\\LeadtoolsMediaStreamingServer.xml");

  //Optional: For Live Streaming
  LiveStreamDevConfig _devconfig;
  LiveStreams streams = mediaServer.GetLiveStreams();
  LiveStream ls = streams.CreateLiveStream();
  _devconfig = ls.DeviceConfig;
  _devconfig.LockDevices();
  ls.VideoDevices["Logitech QuickCam Pro 5000"].Selected = true;
  streams.AddLiveStream(ls);

  mediaServer.SetLiveStreams(streams);
  _devconfig.UnlockDevices();
  //End live streaming setup

mediaServer.Start();
```

The Media Server SDK illustrates this media server in both a self-hosted EXE and as a Windows Service with a management application. It can be used either way.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of the company that wrote this library.